# How to handle GET-Parameter in PHP when modrewrite is activated?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've a little problem.
I use modrewrite to load language-content dynamically into webpage...

example:

www.mydomain.xyz/en (the english version)
www.mydomain.xyz/fr (the french version)
...

My .htaccess:

```
 RewriteRule ^en$ index.html?lang=en
```

But:

*www.mydomain.xyz/en?foo=bar*

and

```
<?php
 if(isset($_GET["foo"])) {
   echo "Yeah! There is some stuff!";
 }
 ?>
```

doesn't work... the GET-Parameter is ignored. What I have to do?

- it works, with *www.meinedomain.xyz/en.html?foo=bar* but I don't want to display any Extensions.

Comment: One way to get rid of this issue is to add &%{QUERY_STRING} at the end as RewriteRule ^en$ index.html?lang=en&%{QUERY_STRING}

Answer (score 2):

Use `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^en$ index.html?lang=en [L,QSA]
```

To make this work for en and fr use this:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/?$ index.html?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

- `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `[QSA]` to your rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^en$ index.html?lang=en [QSA];
```

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

Answer (score 0):

You need the `[QSA]` instruction right after your rewrite rule

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

QSA is "query string append" and preserves query strings on rewrite

I'd also recomment using (/|$) instead of just $, or calling `yourdomain.com/ensomefile.php` would also result in rewriting

```
RewriteRule ^en(/|$) index.html?lang=en [QSA]
```